# Will constructing a sparse graph in NetworkX automatically store the full adjacency matrix?

Tags: python, networkx

If I have a sparse graph that I would like to instantiate as a NetworkX graph and currently have stored as a (say) adjacency dictionary, will it automatically store the data also as a full adjacency matrix (which is very large and thus costly to instantiate), or will the adjacency matrix only be created when explicitly called (or another method requiring it is called)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`Graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/graph.html)

> Edges are represented as links between nodes with optional key/value attributes.

So the `Graph` isn't stored internally as an adjacency matrix. It's stored as something comparable to a dictionary of edge lists. In fact, if we dig into the source a bit, the [`adjacency_matrix`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/linalg/graphmatrix.html#adjacency_matrix) function ends up constructing a SciPy sparse array as well.

```
return nx.to_scipy_sparse_array(G, nodelist=nodelist, dtype=dtype, weight=weight)
```

So even if you *did* construct a full adjacency matrix by calling that function explicitly, it'll use a sparse representation anyway.

You can check `DiGraph` and the others, but they all have a similar comment in the documentation and are stored similarly.